# React Date Range not filling input date fields when selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-input, react-component, daterangepicker

I'm trying to use this react class (react-date-range) to import a date range picker component, however when I select the dates the date is not being updated into both input fields. can anyone help me to identify and resolve it?

Code below and sandBox to:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-date-range';
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'; // main style file
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css'; // theme css file
export default class App extends React.Component {
  handleSelect(ranges){
    console.log(ranges);

  }
  render(){
    const selectionRange = {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      key: 'selection',
    }
    return (
      <DateRangePicker
        ranges={[selectionRange]}
        onChange={this.handleSelect}
      />
    )
  }
}
render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

SandBox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-kapitsa-trglh?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the state changes. You can do like below

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-date-range";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main style file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectionRange : {
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
        key: "selection"
      }
    } 
  }

  handleSelect=(ranges)=> {
    this.setState({
      selectionRange : {
        startDate: ranges.selection.startDate,
        endDate: ranges.selection.endDate,
        key: "selection"
      }
    })
  
    console.log(ranges.selection.endDate);
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
      <DateRangePicker ranges={[this.state.selectionRange]} onChange={this.handleSelect} />
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the state management to update and bind to the `DateRangePicker`:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-date-range";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main style file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      range: {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      key: "selection"
    }};
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleSelect(ranges) {
    this.setState({
      range: ranges.selection
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DateRangePicker ranges={[this.state.range]} onChange={this.handleSelect} />
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```